# Visual Studio prevent accidental checkin of dev testing

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

There are many times when we change code to test something. These are temporary changes that we do not want checking in. For example, I am currently migrating and cleansing a css file into a new css file, and so linked the site to the new css file. I dont want to accidentally check the re-link in, but would like to check the new css file in.

My question is, is there a way I can mark a change such that it does not accidentally get checked in.

Answer (score 1):

Just be sure to review your pending changes before you check them in.  I always give them a quick once over to make sure all the changes are things I intended to change.

Comment: I was just going to say "discipline" and "professionalism".